# Download data error "Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix) [No stack trace available]"

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to add a download button to download the table in the app. I am using the following code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
    titlePanel("Title"),
    selectInput("state", "Select State", unique(ma_pdp$state)),
    selectInput('year', "Select Year", unique(ma_pdp$year)),
    tabPanel("Table", DT::DTOutput('table')))



#Server
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDT({
        ma_pdp %>%
            filter(year == input$year) %>%
            filter(state == input$state) 
        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
            filename = function() {
                paste(input$ma_pdp, ".csv", sep = "")
            },
            content = function(file){
                write.csv(datasetInput, file, row.names=FALSE)
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Am I not referencing the function correctly? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You haven't given us any test data, so I can't test my theory, but nesting one output widget (`output$downloadData`) inside another (`output$table`) looks like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: What’s `datasetInput`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intention is to create a CSV file containing the data currently displayed in `output$table`, this will - I think - give you what you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
  titlePanel("Title"),
  selectInput("state", "Select State", unique(mtcars$cyl)),
  selectInput('year', "Select Year", unique(mtcars$am)),
  tabPanel("Table", DT::DTOutput('table'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  filteredData <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% filter(am == input$year, cyl == input$state) 
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({
    filteredData()
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.csv",
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(filteredData(), file, row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In addition to the observation I made in my comment, I have moved the filtering you do in the `renderTable` function to a separate `reactive`.  This ensures that the data saved by the download handler is consistent with the data displayed in the table without the need for any code duplication.

In the absence of test data, I've used the `mtcars` dataset and made appropriate changes in the code.

Comment: Please read the readily available advice on how to ask a good question and provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.